# C code to mips assembly

Tags: c, mips

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum (int L, int U) {
    if (L == U) return L;
 else {
    int lower, upper;
    int mid = (U+L)/2;
    lower = sum (L, mid);
    upper = sum(mid+1, U);
    return (lower+upper);
 }
}
int main(){
        int x,y;
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        printf("The result is: %d\n",sum(x,y));
}
```

Comment: I think he wants us to manually compile it into MIPS. :P

Comment: Use a C compiler, that is what they are design to do.

Comment: i tried gcc -S hello.c but the result is code in x86 :S

Comment: Many compilers are effectively 2-step compilers: 1st from C to assembler, then from assembler to binary code. On most of them, you can stop compilation before the 2nd step and obtain assembler code file.

Comment: yes i know... is there any tool to make that code in mips assembly?????? :-)

Comment: i'm trying to do this 3 weeks now and i'm verge of a nervous krisis

Comment: You need a cross-compiler... try reading http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/HOWTO/MIPS-HOWTO-9.html for example (or in general google for mips cross compile)

Comment: Try this then http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/bettati/Courses/410/2006C/Projects/gxemulcygwin.html but now I have to ask you a question: have you tried googling? I don't know... for example mips compile windows

Comment: I want to downvote your question, but I presume English is not your first language, so I feel I must resist the urge.  However, in future, please explain what you need better in your questions.  Use google translate (or similar) if you feel you cannot adequately explain it in English.  (I often do this when corresponding with Chinese speakers.)

Answer (score 3):

I will succumb to the temptation of being sarcastic and post this:

```
    .file   1 "hello.c"
    .section .mdebug.abi32
    .previous
    .gnu_attribute 4, 1
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  sum
    .set    nomips16
    .ent    sum
    .type   sum, @function
sum:
    .frame  $sp,40,$31      # vars= 16, regs= 1/0, args= 16, gp= 0
    .mask   0x80000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-40
    sw  $31,36($sp)
    sw  $4,40($sp)
    sw  $5,44($sp)
    lw  $3,40($sp)
    lw  $2,44($sp)
    nop
    bne $3,$2,$L2
    nop

    lw  $2,40($sp)
    j   $L3
    nop

$L2:
    lw  $3,44($sp)
    lw  $2,40($sp)
    nop
    addu    $2,$3,$2
    srl $3,$2,31
    addu    $2,$3,$2
    sra $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,16($sp)
    lw  $4,40($sp)
    lw  $5,16($sp)
    jal sum
    nop

    sw  $2,20($sp)
    lw  $2,16($sp)
    nop
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    move    $4,$2
    lw  $5,44($sp)
    jal sum
    nop

    sw  $2,24($sp)
    lw  $3,20($sp)
    lw  $2,24($sp)
    nop
    addu    $2,$3,$2
$L3:
    lw  $31,36($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,40
    j   $31
    nop

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    sum
    .size   sum, .-sum
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC0:
    .ascii  "%d %d\000"
    .align  2
$LC1:
    .ascii  "The result is: %d\012\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .set    nomips16
    .ent    main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    .frame  $sp,32,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 2/0, args= 16, gp= 0
    .mask   0x80010000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-32
    sw  $31,28($sp)
    sw  $16,24($sp)
    lui $2,%hi($LC0)
    addiu   $3,$2,%lo($LC0)
    addiu   $2,$sp,20
    move    $4,$3
    addiu   $3,$sp,16
    move    $5,$3
    move    $6,$2
    jal scanf
    nop

    lui $2,%hi($LC1)
    addiu   $16,$2,%lo($LC1)
    lw  $3,16($sp)
    lw  $2,20($sp)
    move    $4,$3
    move    $5,$2
    jal sum
    nop

    move    $4,$16
    move    $5,$2
    jal printf
    nop

    lw  $31,28($sp)
    lw  $16,24($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,32
    j   $31
    nop

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    main
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.5.2"
```

This was produced by a GCC cross-compiler I just built for the mips-linux-elf target, using the following command line:

```
mips-linux-elf-gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -S hello.c
```

Since you are using Windows, you should probably search Google for something like `mips cross-compiler for windows`.

What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: to translate this code in mips assembly.... ok thank you everyone for your help :-)